# Maintaining the value of a variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to initialize the content variable in readFile() and want to use this variable in other methods of nodejs. Inside the readFile() content variable is initialized, but outside the scope of this variable is not existing.

```
fs = require('fs');   
var flag=0;  
var content="";

fs.readFile('./file.txt', function (err, data) {

if (err) {
    throw err; 
}
  console.log("file reading complete");
  content=data;   
  console.log("data:"+content);  
});

if(content=="")
   console.log("value not set");
```

After compiling this code, i found that the content variable is initialized in readFile(), but it doesn't maintain this value upto end of the code. I want to maintain the scope of this content variable throughout the program, how can i do this task.

I have also tried the callback method style, but using the callback method style is not working in case of running the exec like this,

```
exec(cmd,function(error,stdout,stderr){

});
```

Below is the piece of code,

```
var child = require('child_process');
var terminal = child.exec("java Temp");
var output="";

process.stdin.pipe(terminal.stdin);

terminal.stdin.on("end", function() {
 // process.exit(0);
});

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) { 
output+=data;
// console.log(''+data);  this line prints a=10 b=20
});

terminal.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
output+=data;
});


terminal.stdin.write('10 20');

console.log(""+output); // this line doesn't print any thing.
```

the source of compiled file Temp is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Temp
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=s.nextInt();
    int b=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("a="+a+"  b="+b);
 }
}
```

how can i use the callback method, to work out this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Node.js is asynchronous, the last if condition is performed, while the readFile() operation is running and content is still empty. You will need to add a callback, in order to check the content value once the readFile() operation is done.

You should be able to get the value of the content variable anywhere in your program, but it will be empty until readFile() finished.

```
fs = require('fs');   
var flag=0;  
var content="";

fs.readFile('./file.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err; 
  }

  console.log("file reading complete");
  content=data;   
  check(); // CALLBACK HERE
  console.log("data:"+content);  
});

function check() {
  if(content=="")
     console.log("value not set");
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now that you have posted more code:

I do not understand what it your code does exactly, but you are doing the same mistake as in the initial question. The console.log line at the and is executed, way before any value was ever appended to the output variable.

If you output the output variable here

```
terminal.stdin.on("end", function() {
 console.log(''+output); // Output here
 // process.exit(0);
});
```

then you should get the desired output.

Have a look at the following article, which is explaining the asynchronous model in Node.js. Its essential to understand this in order to write proper applications.
http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/26/asynchronous-code-design-with-node-js/

Comment: Concerning your edit. I don't see the coherence of exec() and the rest of your question. Could you please provide more details why and how you are using exec()?

Comment: I want to compile and run the programs in my server.

Comment: So you want to run your programs with exec(), as soon as readFile() has finished and the content variable contains a value?

Comment: javascript is not asynchronous, node.js is

Comment: Brother, i want to handle the case of dynamic submission of input in the client browser for processing at the server for displaying the results. thanks for your response

Comment: YesuRaju, you have perhaps misunderstood how NodeJS works. There is no compilation. Running the code is just about executing (in a bash) the node command on a given source file (.js). You don't need to use exec which spawn another process to execute anything. Please give more details of your program structure if you want additional help.

Comment: I have updated and given the full code, now have a look through my code now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a sync version of fs.readFile:

```
 var content = fs.readFileSync("filepath");
```